# Generic subclassable static method that returns instance of subclass

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to define a static factory method that returns an instance of the class it is called on which can be overridden in a subclass. I'm having trouble with getting TypeScript to figure out the correct types.

Basic idea:

```
class FooA {
    static bar() {
        return new this();
    }
}

class FooB extends FooA {
}

// b is type FooA
const b = FooB.bar();
```

In order to get it to understand that `b` was of type `FooB` I had to do this:

```
class FooA {
    static bar<M extends typeof FooA>(this: M) {
        return <InstanceType<M>> new this();
    }
}

class FooB extends FooA {
}

// b is type FooB
const b = FooB.bar();
```

But now I have a problem when I try to override `bar` in `FooB`.

```
class FooA {
    static bar<M extends typeof FooA>(this: M) {
        return <InstanceType<M>> new this();
    }
}

// Class static side 'typeof FooB' incorrectly extends base class
// static side 'typeof FooA'.
//   - The types returned by 'bar()' are incompatible between these types.
//     - Type 'FooB' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<M>'.
class FooB extends FooA {
    static bar() {
        return new this();
    }
}
```

In order to get things working again I need all the boilerplate again when defining `bar` on `FooB`.

```
class FooA {
    static bar<M extends typeof FooA>(this: M) {
        return <InstanceType<M>> new this();
    }
}

class FooB extends FooA {
    static bar<M extends typeof FooA>(this: M) {
        return <InstanceType<M>> new this();
    }
}

// b is type FooB
const b = FooB.bar();
```

The thing is, I really don't want users who are extending my generic class `FooA` to have to use all that boilerplate just to override my `bar` method. Is there a way I can allow people to define subclasses in the following way while still maintaining the correct return types? It seems like the idea is pretty straight forward: *`static bar()` returns an instance of the class it is called on, whatever class that is.*

Answer (score 0):

i think you will always need the overwriting method in the `FooB` class, since the constructors of `FooA` and `FooB` could have different signatures.
For example:

```
class FooA {
    static bar() {
        return new this(1); // <- typescript cannot determine parameters for FooB what can lead to undetected type errors
    }
    constructor(a: number) {

    }
}

class FooB extends FooA {
    constructor(a: string, b: number) {
        super(b);
    }
}
```

Therefore, your third options without any annotations would be save and working:

```
class FooA {
    static bar() {
        return  new this();
    }
}

class FooB extends FooA {
    static bar() {
        return new this();
    }
}

Foo.bar() // returns type of FooB
```